# Can I use another encoding in node.js when I use fs.readFile()

Tags: node.js

Can I use tis620 or windows874 encoding for fs.readFile() in node.js

When I use 'utf8' in database show � or ?.

Thanks.

Satit Rianpit

Comment: Yes, It an error : Unknow encoding.

Comment: no way to use utf8 or utf16 ? I'm sorry I'm not too familiar with asian encodings.

Comment: What are you doing with the contents of the file?

Comment: @ebohlman I read csv file for import to mongodb but my csv file is tis620 encoding node can't convert to utf8 because I open it with utf8.